# Iphone event handling

Tags: iphone, event-handling

i am new to iphone development i have doubts in event handling ,

i wonder how to handle event for the view which having various subview ,imageview etc

bacause if i made touchbegin evnt all the touches made in that view will be refelected how can i find where the touch come from that view (for eg its from Views or imageView or scroll view)

pls help me thanks in adivance

Answer (score 0):

If `touch` points to a `UITouch` object, `touch.view` will give you the view in which the touch occurred. See the documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks u Ole Begemann
but is there any best technique to handel this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

If you define a view in the Interface Builder and enable the "`User Interaction Enabled`" option in the `View Attributes` tab, that view will be able to receive those `touchesBegan` / `touchesMoved` / `touchesEnded` events.